# How to add more channels to input tensors in tensorflow?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Currently, I have an input tensor with only one channel. I'm trying to figure out how to add additional channels.

For example, lets say the current input 8x8 channel one is -

```
 01, 02,...08, 
 09, 10,...16, 
 .
 .
 57, 58,...64
```

And I want to add two more channels (filled with zeroes) of 8x8 -

```
 0, 0,...0, 
 0, 0,...0, 
 .
 .
 0, 0,...0
```

My current code (accepts lists of size 64 and reshapes into 8x8 of 1 channel)-

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 64])
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 8, 8, 1])

input = [1, 2, ...64] #list of 64 items
train_step_policy.run(feed_dict={x: [input], y: [some output list]}, session= sess)
```

To add 2 more channels, I've changed the code to this -

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 64*3])
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 8, 8, 3])

input = [1, 2, ...64] #list of 64 items
#Inserted 2 more items after each item in the input list
temp = [0*64]
inputchannel3 = [[]]
for b1 in input:
    del temp[:]
    for b2 in b1:
        temp += [b2] + [0] + [0]
    inputchannel3.append(temp)
train_step_policy.run(feed_dict={x: inputchannel3, y: [some output list]}, session= sess)
```

`inputchannel3` looks like - `[1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, ...64, 0, 0]`

My question is - Is this the right way to add new channels?

The reason I'm asking this is that I'm not clear on how `tf.reshape` would do this reshaping. Would it know to take every 3rd item (as opposed to 3 consecutive items) to create the 3 channels?

Comment: You can add zero tensors in TensorFlow directly by using tf.zeros or tf.zeros_like. Shapes can be found with tensor.get_shape(). tf.concat or tf.stack to form new tensors. This is one way to do the manipulations inside the graph which makes things clean. Otherwise I think you should read up on how reshape works, and format your data in NumPy accordingly.

Comment: @pfredriksen Thanks. The zero tensors thing was just to keep the question simple. Thanks, I'll look into tf.concat and stack. From what I read up about reshape, it looks ok and compiles fine but since this is the first time I've used reshape with more than one channels I'm wondering if someone more knowledgeable than me could confirm that it indeed is the right way to apply use 3 channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question was:

> Is this the right way to add new channels?

The short answer to this is: yes, great job!

The best way to understand what this function does is looking at the documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape
If you have a color image and a RGBRGBRGBRGB array (so channel 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3 etc. ) this is the way to tell tensorflow to create three channels out of it!

As you state:

> inputchannel3 looks like - [1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, ...64, 0, 0]

I think you did everything correct :D

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great! Thank you, the `RGBRGBRGBRGB array` thing makes the data easier to visualize.